# Add partial implementation to abstract method

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, methods, abstract-class

What is the best way to achieve a design where an abstract method is implemented but must also still require implementation from subclasses. This sounds very rusty at the moment so I will illustrate it:

```
abstract class Foo {
    abstract void update();
}

abstract class Bar {
    void update() {
        //Do something
        update_();
        //Do something else
    }

    abstract void update_();
}
```

So basically, I want a way to add some implementation to an abstract method without stopping it propagating. I feel that simply renaming the method will create unclean code.

What is the best way to approach this problem? Is it simply renaming the method? Or is this pattern best avoided altogether?

Comment: There are many subclasses of Foo that are not subclasses of Bar, however, there are also many subclasses of Bar. If I implemented it entirely in subclasses of Bar it would create a lot of redundant code. I am asking if there is a solution to fix this.

Comment: This is basically the template method pattern, which is fine. You should find a better name for the update_ method: one that says what the method is supposed to do, and complies with the standard naming conventions. If you don't want subclasses to be able to (or to accidentally) override the update() method, it should be final.

Comment: Could you do it the other way round ?  Let `useUpdate()` invoke `abstract update()` ?

Comment: @c0der Please clarify. In the current example, the non-abstract method already calls the abstract method.

Comment: Is Java8 default methods relevant for you?

Comment: @JBNizet The idea is that Bar is an intermediary that modifies the behaviour of `update()`. What would be a naming convention for that? Especially if it is multilayered?

Comment: @AmiHollander I can't see how default methods would be relevant to this.

Comment: It depends on your actual functional usecase. Naming is hard, but it's even harder when you don't even know what the class is for (Foo? Bar?), what the update() method does, and what doSomething() and doSomethingElse() actually do. Let's say Bar is in fact Garage, and update() is in fact paintCar(), doSomething() could be choosePaintingColor(), update_() could be applyPainting(), and doSomethingElse() could be dry().

Comment: @JBNizet Ok thanks. I will just try to come up with the most acceptable name I can think of in future. I was just wondering if there is a better way to approach this as when I try to do this it often looks very unclean.

Comment: I don't find it unclean. It's a well-known design pattern. Documenting the methods, choosing good names, saying that Bar.update() is a template method in its documentation of course helps understanding what's going on.

Comment: There are a number of ways. Someone already mentioned Template Method? Maybe not. Strategy DP. You could also use Decorators. Check out the GoF Decorator DP.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do is to create [Strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). Simply you need to create one single abstract class and implement one main method which uses many already not implemented(abstract let's say) methods.